# Javascript: Toggle visibility of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div visible/invisible using java script. I have a function that is supposed to change the visibility to 'none' if the div is visible and to 'visible' if the div is none. However it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

```
<script>
      function toggleTools()
      {
          var element = document.getElementById('divTools');
          if(element.style.visibility=='visible')
          {
              element.style.visibility='hidden';
          }
          else
          {
              element.style.visibility='visible';
          }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: use jquery its a lot easier

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Comment: This should work, post your HTML please.

Comment: Where you call this function?

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/f5Hts/

Comment: @Mr.coder "When your only tool is a hammer..."

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 34): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DZvB/).

Comment: Works fine as long as you initially set the visibility: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c63pa/

Comment: @GeorgeCummins what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Mr.coder - It means there's absolutely no reason to load all of jQuery for something so simple.

Comment: but @GeorgeCummins there is no guarantee he is using only this peice of script in his entire website

Comment: Also, if you reference a CDN rather than hosting your own copy of jQuery, there's a pretty good chance the user already has it cached.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not jQuery is feasible, he didn't tag this post with it, so the accepted answer should be in raw Javascript.

Comment: Gents.. His code is working.

Comment: Hi @j08691, your answer is correct but it is posted as a comment. Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: @user3542962 - sure, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried Your Code and Its Working For me. Please Find Below Code. Set Visibility for the Element initially Otherwise its not working at the beginning.

```
 <script>
          function toggleTools()
          {
              var element = document.getElementById('divTools');
              if(element.style.visibility=='visible')
              {
                  element.style.visibility='hidden';
              }
              else
              {
                  element.style.visibility='visible';
              }

          }
        </script>

    <div id="divTools" style="visibility:visible">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="toggleTools()" value="click" />
```

Comment: We can see by the comments it works. This however, is not an answer.

Comment: He needs to use visibility initially. Otherwise initially it is not working. Can you please remove your DOWNVOTE..

Comment: Downvote's not mine amigo. Someone probably just agreed with me.

Comment: Still you think this is not the answer. I edited it and let me know whether it need to remove or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go with

```
document.getElementById('divTools').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('divTools').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Why can't he use visibility?

Comment: There is a difference.   If you set display:none, it hides the entire element, while visibility:hidden means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size.

Comment: So when visibility didn't work, you thought setting a different CSS property instead would work ?

Comment: He didn't exactly specify what "doesn't work" meant.  So my thinking was, try a different method, get different results.  And I'm not the only person that made such a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<script>
      function toggleTools()
      {
          var element = document.getElementById('divTools');
          if(element.style.display!='none')
          {
              element.style.display='none';
          }
          else
          {
              element.style.display='block';
          }
      }
    </script>
```

But you can use JQuery.

```
$('#divTools').toggle();
```

Comment: Why can't he use visibility?

Comment: Because visibility have problems in some browsers, jQuery always use display:block; and display:none;

Comment: There are no issues with visibility in any browsers that I know of? What browsers would that be, and what are the issues?

Comment: This is the problem, commented by @durbnpoisn : There is a difference. If you set display:none, it hides the entire element, while visibility:hidden means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size.

Answer (score 0):

The last thing don't work it's the first time whom charge the page. I check if visibility == '' and this works.

```
function toggleTools()
      {
          var element = document.getElementById('divTools');
          if(element.style.visibility=='visible' || element.style.visibility=='')
          {
              element.style.visibility='hidden';
          }
          else
          {
              element.style.visibility='visible';
          }
      }
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Magicianred/9vTeR/1/

Enjoy your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, provided you set the visibility initially:

via CSS:

```
#divTools {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c63pa/)**

Or via JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('divTools').style.visibility='hidden';
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U6pXA/)**